# Cannot read string data from table row. But when I put "" data, it works

Tags: eosio-code, string

```
//@abi action
    void testhand() {
        gamecurrents gamecurrenttable(_self, _self);
        auto existing = gamecurrenttable.find( _self ); 
        if(existing == gamecurrenttable.end()) { 
            gamecurrenttable.emplace(_self,[&](auto& thisrow)
            {
                thisrow.account = _self;
                thisrow.hand = 'a'; // DO NOT WORK
                thisrow.version = 1;
            });
        }else{
            eosio::print( "Edit here, ", hand );
            gamecurrenttable.modify( existing, 0,[&](auto& thisrow){
                thisrow.hand = "";  // WORK !!
                thisrow.version = 2;
            });
        }
    }
```

First I run the above action.

```
 ./cleos push action (myeosid) testhand '[]' -p (myeosid)
```

After than, I fetch the row

```
cleos get table (myeosid) (myeosid) gamecurrent
```

error occured

```
Error 3015013: Unpack data exception
Error Details:
Unable to unpack built-in type 'string' while processing 'gamecurrent.hand' read datastream of length 32 over by -4
```

But when I put "" data, it works. (when I run above test action again. it will update data by "")

```
     "rows": [{
      "account": (myeosid),
      "price": "0.0000 SYS",
      "version": 2,
      "count": 0,
      "hand": "",
      "date": 0
    }
  ],
  "more": false
```

the struct is

```
/// @abi table gamecurrent i64
    struct gamecurrent{
        account_name account;
        asset price;
        uint8_t version;
        string hand;
        ..
        uint64_t primary_key() const { return account;}
        EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(gamecurrent,(account)(price)(version)(hand)..)
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code and i also have coded in updated version of eosio compiler i.e, eosio.cdt my code to modify table data is look like this

```
void tablecheck::updatedata ( capi_name user , string name )
{
    require_auth( _self );// requires authorization of contract owner
    checktb ctbl(_self, user);
    auto it = ctbl.find(user);

    // adding account name to userstats table
    ctbl.modify(it,_self, [&](auto &p) {
            p.name = "z";

    });
}
```

Table structure is like

```
    struct [[eosio::table, eosio::contract("tablecheck")]]
    checktbl {
        capi_name user;
        string name;


        capi_name primary_key() const { return user; }
        EOSLIB_SERIALIZE( checktbl ,(user) (name)  );
    };
```

And i executed this command (tablecheck12 is my account name)

**cleos get table tablecheck12 tablecheck12 checktbl**

I got this result

```
{
  "rows": [{
      "user": "tablecheck12",
      "name": "z"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

So it works for me in new compiler you got error may be because of compiler you can try it out using [eosio.cdt](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt)

Comment: Right. The compiler was updated. I did not test on that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the C++ expert but I think you are trying to use the wrong data type in the string.

If you use a single quotes 'a' - that is a char value and not a string.
You probably meant a string with a single character in it. Try using double quotes "a".

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I tried double quotation again ( thisrow.hand = "a"; ) But same result.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(gamecurrent,(account)(price)(version)(hand)..)`, and then redeploy it for another account.